# Как подсчитать значения из двух Dataframe, по разным строкам и нескольким условиям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

имеется два Dataframe, у них есть 2 общих столбца. Нужно подсчитать  количество значений исходя из данных нескольких столбцов. Есть ли возможность реализовать это без циклов, только возможностями pandas?
Ссылка на таблицы для Dataframe: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/5lR5cUi-dhyOrA

```
df1
Out[58]: 
   name Type Type_2  Type_3
0  Ваня    x     G9       1
1  Ваня    x    D18       1
2  Ваня    y     G9       2
3  Ваня    y    D18       1
4  Вика    x     G9       3
5  Вика    y    D18       3
6  Леша    x     G9       2
7  Леша    y    D18       1
8  Леша    y     G9       2

df2
Out[59]: 
   name Type_2  Type_4
0  Ваня     G9       4
1  Ваня    D18       3
2  Вика     G9       4
3  Вика    D18       4
4  Леша     G9       5
5  Леша    D18       3
```

Должно получится так:

```
resdf
Out[61]: 
   name Type_count_1 Type_count_2 Type_count_3
0  Ваня            q            w            e
1  Вика            q            w            e
2  Леша            q            w            e
```

Формулы примерно такие:

```
Q (x)= Type_4(Type_2) — Type_3(Type_2)
W (y) = Type_4(Type_2) — Type_3(Type_2)
E (y) = summ Type_3
```

то есть **q** это разница между значением столбца **Type_4** и **Type_3** с одинаковым значением **Type_2** для строк с **х** в столбце **Type** в **df1**;
 **w** - это тоже самое, только для значений **y**; 
 **e** - сумма значений столбца **Type_3** для значений **y**.
 Объяснил как мог, что-бы было понятно, если что попытаюсь разъяснить более понятно. Например для Вики:
q = 4 - 3 = 1 
w = 4 - 3 = 1 
e = 3 
У других больше значений x и y, соответственно после будет сумма результатов

Comment: Ну тут явно нужно сделать сначала столбцы с вычетом колонок друг из друга, потом `groupby`, потом ещё `pivot`. Но это нужно сидеть и думать всё по шагам. Так сходу не накидать.

Answer (score 0):

Подобные вопросы надо как-то разбивать, что-ли, на части. В общем, если я правильно понял задачу, то можно просто сделать как-то так:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, on=["name", "Type_2"])
res["QW"] = res["Type_4"] - res["Type_3"]
res["E"] = res.loc[res["Type"]=="y"].groupby("name")["Type_3"].transform(sum)
```

в столбце QW будут ваши q и w в соответствии с Type.

```
   name Type Type_2  Type_3  Type_4  QW    E
0  Ваня    x     G9       1       4   3  NaN
1  Ваня    y     G9       2       4   2  3.0
2  Ваня    x    D18       1       3   2  NaN
3  Ваня    y    D18       1       3   2  3.0
4  Вика    x     G9       3       4   1  NaN
5  Вика    y    D18       3       4   1  3.0
6  Леша    x     G9       2       5   3  NaN
7  Леша    y     G9       2       5   3  3.0
8  Леша    y    D18       1       3   2  3.0
​
```

Comment: Да, у меня плюс минус так и получалось, только я не могу прийти к результату как в resdf, и плюс задачка усложнилась тем, что для q и w для значений x и y, если их несколько, считается остаток после первой разности по значениям Type_2. Например у Вани q для x и G9 будет 4 -1 = 3, соответственно w для y и G9 будет уже 3-2 =1. Если один x и один y, то все работает замечательно, но если их несколько то получается белиберда :)